# Find all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ that satisfy every $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ s.t. $2^{(k-1)n+1} \nmid \frac{(kn)!}{n!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem : Find all positive integers k that satisfy every positive integer n that $ 2^{(k-1)n+1}$  is not a divisor of   $\frac{(kn)!}{n!}$
This is all i did :

Legendre's formula : $v_2$(n!) = n-$S_n$(2).(where $S_n$(2) is the sum of the digits of n in the 2 . factorization system )

What must prove is equivalent to :

$v_2$( $\frac{(kn)!}{n!}$) $\lt$ (k-1)n+1

kn-$S_{kn}$(2)  -n+$S_n$(2) < (k-1)n+1

$S_n$(2)-$S_{kn}$(2)<1;

So , we need to find a positive integer k such that for every positive integer n :  $S_n$(2)-$S_{kn}$(2)<1;

It is easy to see that for k = $2^z$  then $S_n$(2)-$S_{kn}$(2)=0  (satisfied with z being an integer)

At this point I am completely out of ideas, maybe k is just like that, but I still can't prove that hypothesis. This is a really interesting and fascinating issue for me . Can you give me some ideas or suggestions?

Comment: @hardmath Hi, I think this problem is really interesting and difficult. it's well worth a try. Of course I'm sure it's not wrong

Comment: You really should use MathJax consistently, your post is hard to parse. Here's a hint for the answer: try to find the inequality between $\lfloor \frac{kn}{2^a} \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{n}{2^a} \rfloor$ and $\frac{(k-1)n}{2^a}$. The sum of a geometric series will also aid.

Comment: @arbashn Can you be more specific, I've been thinking about your suggestion for almost 2 hours and still no progress. Thank you very much

Comment: @arbashn Actually your suggestion was the first idea that came to my mind , but that time I worked all day and it did not solve the problem .

Comment: @arbashn hey help me ! please !

Comment: Nevermind, my proof was wrong. I had initially assumed that it works for all $k$, but I don't think it's necessarily true.

Comment: @arbashn You should remember that this problem has a complete k satisfying .

Comment: @arbashn I think this problem only k = 2^z satisfy the problem , that's my idea , worth a try ?

Comment: @arbashn easy to see with k = 2^z satisfying the problem.

Comment: @arbashn hey , can you vote for my question to be more known ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that says that $v_p(n!)=\frac{n-S_p(n)}{p-1}$, where $S_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits in the base $p$ representation of $n$. Using this we get $v_2\frac{(kn)!}{n!}=(k-1)n+(S_p(n)-S_p(kn) )$.

So the number $k$ must satisfy that $kn$ has sum of digits greater than or equal to $n$ for any $n$ (in binary).

Notice that $k$ satisfies this if and only if $2k$ satisfies this, so we must only prove that the only odd integer that works is $k=1$.

Suppose an odd $k>1$ works. Let $m$ be a multiple of $k$ with the least possible number of "one" bits (suppose it has $v$ bits). Write $m=2^a+b$ with $2^a>b$. Notice that the number $w=2^{a+s\varphi(k)}+b$ is also a multiple of $k$ with $v$ bits for every $s\in \mathbb Z^+$.

We now prove that $w/k$ must have more than $v$ bits for sufficiently large $s$.We proceed by contradiction, pick $s$ so that $w/k$
must have at least $z$ consecutive zeros in its binary representation, where $z$ is equal to the length of the base $2$ representation of $k$. Then the number of bits in $w/k\times k$ is equal to the sum of the bits of $k$ multiplied by each of the two parts of $w/k$, and this is at least $2v$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: what is $\varphi(k)$?

Comment: euler's totient function.

Comment: @mathworker21. We are using the $2^a \equiv 2^{a+s\varphi(k)} \bmod k$ for odd $k$, which is a consequence of euler's theorem.

Comment: yea ik, thx ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, does the answer seem correct to you?

Comment: i think so. i will check carefully when i have time (and then upvote if it's correct). i had trouble finding the correct choice for $w$; congrats if yours is correct

Comment: Have a great rest of your day :D

Answer (score -1):

Well here is an attempt...

$\frac{(kn)!}{n!}$ means there are $kn-n = n(k-1)$ numbers left meaning $\frac{n(k-1)}{2}$ evens and  $\frac{n(k-1)}{2}$ number of 2's in the number and  $\frac{n(k-1)}{4}$ number of more 2's (from the numbers with 4 as a multiple) and  $\frac{n(k-1)}{8}$ number of more 2's (from the numbers with 8 as a multiple) and on and on......

Such that, $$n(k-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+.....\right) = n(k-1)$$

which will still be not equal to the number of 2's in $2^{(k-1)n} \times 2 $

So all positive integers could be $k$ (Some logistics are off but you get the point.)

Comment: but all positive integers can't be $k$.